# Cross Platform GPU Computing

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl, thrust

Recently gone through [Thrust](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#axzz4K9OPc1Tr). Is it cross platform? If it is how do I build it? I couldn't find any documentation related to build thrust.Can anyone shed any light on this?

Alternatively, does anyone know of any other C++ libraries that support cross platform GPU computing (other than openCL)?

Answer (score 1):

Right under "installation and versioning" it says

> Since Thrust is a template library of header files, no further installation is necessary to start using Thrust.

Installing the CUDA toolkit should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is applicable for android & iOS too?

Comment: @jhon: Where did you find an iOS device with an NVIDIA GPU??